# How to add whitespace after string.punctuation in Python?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I want to clean my reviews data. Here's my code :

```
def processData(data):
    data = data.lower() #casefold    
    data = re.sub('<[^>]*>',' ',data) #remove any html     

    data = re.sub(r'#([^\s]+)', r'\1', data) #Replace #word with word
    remove = string.punctuation
    remove = remove.replace("'", "") # don't remove '
    p = r"[{}]".format(remove) #create the pattern
    data = re.sub(p, "", data)

    data = re.sub('[\s]+', ' ', data) #remove additional whitespaces

    pp = re.compile(r"(.)\1{1,}", re.DOTALL) #pattern for remove repetitions 
    data = pp.sub(r"\1\1", data)

    return data
```

This code almost work well, but there still a problem. 
For this sentence "she work in public-service" ,

I got "she work in publicservice".

The problem is there are no whitespace after string punctuation.

I want my sentence to be like this "she work in public service".

Can you help me with my code?

Comment: Do you want to add a white space after punctuation? Or replace with punctuation? please clarify.

Comment: What is "re" in your code?

Comment: @AhsanulHaque Actually, I want to add whitespace after remove string punctuation. But replace punctuation with whitespace maybe will work too.

Comment: @Michael re is regex operations

Comment: @ReiraVR See my answer then.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want this:

```
>>> st = 'she works in public-service'
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'([{}])'.format(string.punctuation),r' ',st)
'she works in public service'
>>>
```

Comment: It works, but it will remove Apostrophe. I don't want to remove Apostrophe. So i'm using the code below : 

remove = string.punctuation
remove = remove.replace("'", "") # don't remove ' (Apostrophe)

Comment: @Ahsanul: To add whitespace **after** the punctuation, you need to modify the sub line by `re.sub(r'([{}])'.format(string.punctuation),r'\1 ',st)`. In your case, you just drop the punctuation.